# why wordpress facebook widget show only in russian?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, widget

from any country i am accessing the website i see the widget in Russian language

on link: [website](https://www.obeyyourbodyskincare.com)

the widget on the on the bottom is facebook widget.

anyone run into this same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one.   There was a thread about his exact problem on the [Wordpress Support site](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/language-14)

The iframe src attribute on that site contain `locale=uk_UA` in the query string.  If you have control of that, simply remove that field, and the widget locale will default to the user's browser setting.

Compare [locale specified](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=728363513897537&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FdgdTycPTSRj.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df2eb3cc4866254c%26domain%3Dwww.obeyyourbodyskincare.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.obeyyourbodyskincare.com%252Ffcbc716ec55e76%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.obeyyourbodyskincare.com%2F&locale=uk_UA&ref=widget&sdk=joey&share=true&show_faces=true&width=450) vs [unspecified](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=728363513897537&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FdgdTycPTSRj.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df2eb3cc4866254c%26domain%3Dwww.obeyyourbodyskincare.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.obeyyourbodyskincare.com%252Ffcbc716ec55e76%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.obeyyourbodyskincare.com%2F&ref=widget&sdk=joey&share=true&show_faces=true&width=450)